# Random Number generator in XML File c#

Tags: c#

I wonder if it is possible to generate a random number for a specific node in a xml file. I tried to do( code sample below) but I got an exception
(InvalidOperationException: 
system invalid operation exception the value for the following node type can not be set: 'Element' )
I'm a beginner in c# programming, so any Idea how to do it without the exception show up.
Thanks in advance.

[Code Sample random number to node Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYQrH.png)

Comment: Leave the code here not on any server in the form of graphics that will disappear in a few weeks. Please see how to create an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you wrote you can't use the Value property.

The XmlNode has an InnerText node, so you just need to use it, as can be seen bellow:

```
    XmlNode node = someDoc.FirstChild;
    string number = new Random().Next(100).ToString();
    node.InnerText = number;
```

But if for some reason you want to use the Value property, you need to do something like this instead:

```
    string number = new Random().Next(100).ToString();
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//SomeXPath");
    node.Value = number;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , I just used xDocument and XpathSelectElement to overcome the Exception Problem,by selecting the node directely and change it value. Its similar to your second suggestion with SelectSingleNode

Comment: @agsmi you can see how to do that in the following link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work